# Remove HTML code and output in PHP destination url

Tags: php, html

I wanted to pull out html code Target URL and forgive with a variable

```
<a href="https://www.test.de/adtrack/3a10056f3.html" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.test.de/adtrack/3a10056f3.img" border="0" /></a>

$url = https://www.test.de/adtrack/3a10056f3.html
```

the $url wants to echo that too in php

Comment: i just want to have the url <a href = " and " target="_blank">to be removed <?php echo $url ?>

Answer (score 0):

Just echo the whole thing with your variable added in it.

```
$url = 'https://www.test.de/adtrack/3a10056f3.html'
echo '<a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.test.de/adtrack/3a10056f3.img" border="0" /></a>';
```

or, echo it inside your html like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.test.de/adtrack/3a10056f3.img" border="0" /></a>
```

If you do as above, remember that your file extension should be ".php" and not ".html" or else it won't work.

Comment: $htmlstring = "<a href='link.html'>fasljsadf</a> allkasdflajksdf <a href='link2.html'>fasljsadf</a> 564564 <a href='link3.html'>fasljsadf</a>";
preg_match_all('/href=["|\'](.*?)["|\']/i',$htmlstring,$matches);

print_r($matches[1]); Returns:

Array
(
[0] => link.html
[1] => link2.html
[2] => link3.html
)